# How can i upload my website?

Tags: bootstrap-4, cpanel, website-deployment

I'm new to web design. I built a simple website by bootstrap studio and I've exported it. I got a free domain/host from Biz.nf to upload my website. I uploaded my folders  (css-js-img-bootstrap) and index.html file in one folder in file manager that already exists but when I open my website in the browser  (firefox) it shows me wrong design with no image and any style.

Please help me solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: It is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/styles.css">`.

Comment: yes it is. it works nice.thank you but answer me how to accept your answer. i think if you answer it and i accept your answer its better for you.by the way thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Thanks. It’s ok. %)P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use ../ to set your *css file directory to find it from another folder.